# Am I using correct preposition with proper clauses?

Tags: prepositions, clauses

I am writing the following text.

> Although, we obtained a satisfactory results for this analysis, we cannot say that the same precision can be obtained with respect to field measurements. After this idea, I would like to give reasons why it has happened so.

> This is mainly due to the error in model fitting **from** less number of points lie on a short-arc **in** the circle perimeter. **This error** may be leading to a larger circle than that in reality.

Do you think I am using the correct prepositions?

I combine those two paragraphs into one, as follows.

> This is mainly due to the error in model fitting **from** less number of points lie on a short-arc **within** the circle perimeter, **which in turn** may be leading to a larger circle than that in reality.

Am I correctly using the clause which combines the above two sentences?

Comment: This question borders on being proof-reading. Then, I don't see how we can answer to "I am also not sure whether I am using the correct clauses in order to describe my supportive ideas."

Comment: I think it *is* proofreading. There are just too many errors to be meaningfully addressed in a single ELL answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many grammatical errors in your sentences. Let's get rid of them first. Then we can deal with the semantics.

> Although we obtained {a satisfactory result/ satisfactory results [CHOOSE ONE]} from this analysis, we cannot say that the same precision can be obtained for field measurements. This is primarily because of an error in model fitting caused by the small number of points on a short-arc within the circle perimeter, which in turn may lead to a larger circle than is really there.

If I understood what this paragraph was talking about -- I'd need to see a picture -- perhaps I could provide a better revision. But this is math, and I'm not a mathematician.

Here's another version:

> Although this analysis yielded a satisfactory result, the same precision cannot be obtained for field measurements, primarily because of a model-fitting error caused by the small number of points on a short-arc within the circle perimeter, which in turn may lead to a larger circle than is really there.

I don't know whether this is what you want the sentence to say. It seems to me that this includes all your points in 49 words rather than in 63 or the original 75.

What do you think?